# Angular Keep files when I select others to add

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function to add images and preview them. I selected 3 images, these 3 images are displayed, but if you try to insert one more image, those three uploaded disappear and only visible to what I uploaded at that moment.

Is there a way to increment the images? That is, if I added 3 and then want to add another image, I get 4 and not 1.

How can I do this?

[Stackblitz  ---> My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqktnl)

**Html**

```
<div class="drop">

      <ng-container *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
          <img [src]="urls[0]"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(urls[0])"><img src="./assets/cruz.svg"></span>
        </ng-container>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
          <img [src]="url"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(url)"><img src="./assets/cruz.svg"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Component**

```
files:any;

   urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    this.urls = [];
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files.length < 7 ) {

      for (let file of this.files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);    
      }
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing your urls array every time the detectFiles function is called ( new images are selected)

just delete this line : this.urls = [];

**Component**

```
files:any;

   urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    //this.urls = [];
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files.length < 7 ) {

      for (let file of this.files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);    
      }
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here as mentioned by 'Z.bolbol' above.
Understanding the scope. The urls array should be declared at global or root level. You have it at lexial scope which makes the urls array to initiate every time you hit the method.

Comment: Thanks to try help me ! best regards